# Laravel and Flatpack Page Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Has anybody used [Flatpack Page Builder](https://themeforest.net/item/flatpack-landing-pages-pack-with-page-builder/10591107) along with Laravel? I have a Laravel website and I want to add a "create email template" feature, that's why I bought Flatpack. How do I add it to my site? Do I add a subdomain `mysite.xyz/builder` and upload the builder files there or do I play with Laravel's routing and add the builder files in Laravel (somewhere which I don't know too). Please help.